# Include detail in table of figures that is not in the caption

Tags: microsoft-word, links, caption, cross-reference

I've got completely stuck on something that should be trivial: I am working with MS Word 2003, and am putting together a table of figures. I need to have more detail in the table of figures than I have in the caption. For example, in the caption I have:

Fig 1: John and Jenny in London

and in the table of figures I need to the source and accessed date:

Fig 1: John and Jenny in London, available at www.johnandjenny.com, accessed 03/09/2013

I have tried using hidden text in the caption, but the hidden text is not included in the table of figures. The only other thing I can think of is to include all of the detail in the caption, but make the bit that I don't want to show white. This is not ideal, because sometimes the additional detail is several lines long, and this will create a dead space in the caption.

Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a better way to do this, but FYI this is a common want when it comes to regular table of contents as well, for example when you want to insert text before the page number. The best way I have come across to achieve this is using the white text on white background trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting a TC field as well, e.g. something like this:

Insert the caption you want in the usual way, so you have, e.g.

Fig { SEQ Figure \*Arabic }: John and Jenny in London

Then follow that by a { TC } field like this:

{ TC "Fig { SEQ Figure \*Arabic \c }: John and Jenny in London, available at www.johnandjenny.com, accessed 03/09/2013" \f "TCFig" }

where both sets of { } have to be the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word.

Then instead of inserting a Figures TOC field like { TOC \c "Figure" } or whatever, use { TOC \f "TCFig" }

A problem with this is that if you also want to use { TOC \c "Figure" }, it will no longer work properly. In that case you could use a different SEQ sequence name and a SEQ field with no \c, but you would have to ensure that there was one of these TC fields for every figure. e.g.

{ TC "Fig { SEQ TCFig \*Arabic }: John and Jenny in London, available at www.johnandjenny.com, accessed 03/09/2013" \f "TCFig" }